# How to Make looping Execute When Statement Is False in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scheduled-tasks, datetimepicker

I Make WinForms App for execute ssis package , and i want to make timer with datepicker so when i choose datepicker at 5pm the method will be executed at 5pm. I Have difficulty to make that happen first i tried this with do while but it will just stop executing when the statement is false and will always executing when statement is true, what i want to create is otherwise, i want to the looping is like checking not executing , so it will always looping for checking and will be executed only when statement is true

```
do
{
    Executed();
}
//Label3 is DateTimeNow
while (dateTimePicker1.Text == label3.Text);
```

so the logic is something like that, but the opposite way, the code will looping until the statement is true when normally the statement start from true and will stop looping when statement false, and what i try to achive is the statement is start from false and will keep checking till statement is true. Can we do that ? thanks

Comment: Instead of having a loop to check that, you should rely on events of the `dateTimePicker1` and exectue the task when the text is what you are looking for.

Comment: hmm maybe you right , so when datTimePicker == label3 then execute ?

Comment: but what should i use ? i cant use if else either because my statement will start from false condition

Comment: What's the control type `dateTimePicker1`? Is it a `DateTimePicker`?

Comment: yeah its DateTimePicker, like this "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";

Comment: so the workflow will work like this, i set the datetimepicker then i create a do while or if else  condition and then the method will be executed only when datetimepicker.text is same as label3 (Datetime now)

Comment: Instead of having a loop to check whether the value of `DateTimePicker` is desired, you should use a `Timer` to check if the `DateTime.Now` is the desired time.

Comment: @RezaAghaei oh you mean use tick event ? and i will add method if datetimepicker = label3 then execute lis that what you mean ? so i need set the interval to 0 or 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a loop to check whether the value of `DateTimePicker` is desired, you should use a `Timer` and handle its `Tick` event to check if the `DateTime.Now` is the desired time:

```
bool handled = false;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var d1 = DateTime.Now;
    var d2 = dateTimePicker1.Value;

    if (d1.Year == d2.Year && d1.Month == d2.Month && d1.Day == d2.Day &&
        d1.Hour == d2.Hour && d1.Minute == d2.Minute)
    {
        if (!handled) //Allow running once
        {
            handled = true;
            DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note 1:** To make above example working, make sure you set the `Interval` property of the timer to `30000` to run every `30` seconds and also `Start` the timer whenever you want the scheduler start monitoring. Then the `DoSomething` method will run at exact time (up to minute level) which you set using `DateTimePicker`. You can change the criteria based on your requirement, for example to make it run every day at the specified time, you can remove `d1.Day == d2.Day`.

**Note 2:** :Scheduling libraries like [Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net) are created to let you create scheduled task in your application easily.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to check if the time has *passed* rather than checking for an exact match? I guess with a thirty second interval you're pretty much guaranteed a match but I would think generally it might be "better" (in case the interval were increased, for example). However I guess it depends since OP only states he wants it to run *at* the given time, but says nothing about if that time were missed for whatever reason.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 It's just an example. OP knows the requirement better. Personally I'd say, user mean to run the task *On* the specific time. But the implementation can simply change to satisfy your requirement as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the not operator "!"

```
while (dateTimePicker1.Text != label3.Text);
```

Comment: Probably you mean `!=`

Comment: Yeah thanks, I'm new to C# string getting used to the syntax.

Comment: no thats not what i ask, what i ask is how to make loop always checking not executing and will just execute when statement is true and then stop the looping

Comment: My thoughts exactly SAN. Because you want the code to be executed when the statement is true then the loop must be the opposite for it to continually check it. Otherwise like you pointed out Theodorus it would execute the code instantly instead of waiting.

Comment: hmm this is so hard to explain , maybe i cant do this with do while